How to select high frame rate to capture Live Photos?
I'm borrowing some code to get higher framerate than the default 30, but not all of these formats support Live Photo and I can't find a way to check for it - any ideas?
var bestFormat: AVCaptureDevice.Format?
                var bestFrameRateRange: AVFrameRateRange?

                for format in deviceInput.device.formats {
                    if format.supportlive
                    let supporrtedFrameRanges = deviceInput.device.activeFormat.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges
                    for frameRange in supporrtedFrameRanges {
                        if frameRange.maxFrameRate > bestFrameRateRange?.maxFrameRate ?? 0 {
                            bestFormat = format
                            bestFrameRateRange = frameRange
                        }
                        Log.debug("livePhoto frameRange:\(frameRange) format:\(format)")
                    }
                }

                if let bestFormat, let bestFrameRateRange {
                    do {
                        try deviceInput.device.lockForConfiguration()

                        deviceInput.device.activeFormat = bestFormat

                        // Set the device's min/max frame duration.
                        let duration = bestFrameRateRange.minFrameDuration
                        deviceInput.device.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = duration
                        deviceInput.device.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = duration

                        deviceInput.device.unlockForConfiguration()
                        Log.debug("livePhoto didSet bestFrameRateRange:\(bestFrameRateRange)")

                    } catch {
                        Log.error(error, message: "livePhoto set format failed for:\(bestFrameRateRange)")
                    }
                }

